# Getting Error with this log4j new versions

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, log4j

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQnD3.png)I have the log4j-api-2.11.2.jar and log4j-core-2.11.2.jar imported into my build path. But somehow the following code failed:

```
import java.lang.System.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.*;

public class Demo {

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Demo.class.getName());
}
```

I'm getting an error near `LogManager`. I don't know which java package to import.

Comment: What error are you getting? Use the **[edit]** link to update your post with the exact error message or stack trace.

Comment: `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;`


You'll also want to replace your first import line with
`import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger; `